# How to calculate sum of abs of all off-diagonal elements of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm new to numpy and I want to calculate the sum of abs of all off-diagonal elements of a numpy array. [off-diagonal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/off-diagonal) elements of a matrix are all elements of a matrix except ones that are in the main diagonal of it.

I want to calculate the sum of abs of them so I can implement the [Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm) of [this lecture](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme335/lecture7.pdf)

so, to compute it, I think this code will work:

```
import numpy as np
off_diagonal_sum = 0
for i in range(n): # n is the dimension of our square matrix
    # mat is our matrix
    off_diagonal_sum = off_diagonal_sum + np.sum(np.abs(mat[i, (i + 1):n]))
    off_diagonal_sum = off_diagonal_sum + np.sum(np.abs(mat[i, 0:(i - 1)]))
```

but as I'm new to numpy, I think there should be a simpler and shorter way to compute that. do you have any idea?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a nice option in NumPy called [diag_indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices.html) which returns you the indices of diagonal elements of a 2-d array. Using this, you can get the sum of diagonal elements and subtract it from the sum of complete array `np.sum(arr)` to get the sum of off diagonal elements without using any explicit for-loops. To get the absolute sum, you simply use `np.abs` to get absolute values of each element and then perform the task as follows.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randint(1, 20, size=(3,3)) # Define a random 2d array
print (arr)
dia = np.diag_indices(3) # indices of diagonal elements
dia_sum = sum(arr[dia]) # sum of diagonal elements
off_dia_sum = np.sum(arr) - dia_sum # subtract the diagonal sum from total array sum
print (off_dia_sum)
```

---

```
[[12 19 10]
 [ 3 13 18]
 [16 16  6]]
82
```

**Alternate 1**

You can also use simply `np.trace` to get the sum of diagonal elements and then subtract it from the total array sum to get the sum of the off-diagonal elements.

```
off_dia_sum = np.sum(arr) - np.trace(arr)
```

**Alternate 2**

Using `np.diagonal` to get the diagonal elements and then take the sum and subtract from the total sum as

```
dia_sum = sum(np.diagonal(arr))
off_dia_sum = np.sum(arr) - dia_sum
```

**Alternate 3**

Using list comprehension you can do the following where you only store the elements in the list if it is off diagonal, which means if both indices `i` and `j` are not equal.

```
size = len(arr)
off_dia_sum = sum([arr[i][j] for i in range(size) for j in range(size) if i!=j])
```

Comment: You can use np.abs(arr) to get absolute values of array and then perform the operations I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the trace from the full sum is fast and most of the time perfectly fine.

If, however, off-diagonal elements are much (many orders of magnitude) smaller than diagonal elements, results can become imprecise.

Therefore here are two numpy solutions that are not quite as fast but safer.

```
# make an example with very small off-diag elements

from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

N = 100
A = np.identity(N) + 1e-8*np.random.random((N, N))
A = np.abs(A+A.T) # A is symmetric, also we take the absolute value right here

# method 1
np.bincount(np.identity(N, int).ravel(), A.ravel())[0]
# 9.934386601640464e-05

# method 2 - this only works with symmetric A:
2*squareform(A, checks=False).sum()
# 9.934386601640431e-05

# and the "subtract trace" method
A.sum()-A.trace()
# 9.934386602594714e-05

# with double precision all looks ok in this example
# so for the sake of demonstration let's go to single precision
A = A.astype(np.single)

np.bincount(np.identity(N, int).ravel(), A.ravel())[0]
# 9.93438660777668e-05
2*squareform(A, checks=False).sum()
# 9.93438734440133e-05

# so far so good, but ...

A.sum()-A.trace()
# 7.6293945e-05

# Ouch!
```